# Java timer task runs slower than normal

Tags: java, timer

Part of an application I'm writing uses a chronometer system. The timer should tick once every ms.

In my chronometer, I have these variables.

```
    private static final int DELAY_IN_MILLISECONDS = 0;
    private int intervalInMilliseconds = 1;
```

I start the timer like this:

```
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new Task(), DELAY_IN_MILLISECONDS,
            getIntervalInMilliseconds());
```

Yet, after a second he only reached about +- 100ms instead of 1000ms.

Though he used to work fine, untill I've added code to a different part of the game. I'm rather sure I've changed nothing on the timer but yet he became slower than normal (he used to work fine at first).

Is it possible that my timer runs slower due to the application requiring too much CPU time for other things? (it's a game I'm creating). If so, what would be the conventional way to solve this? Keeping in mind that it's more important the game runs smooth than the timer.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Is there a way to find out which part of your application is "bottlenecking" it, such as check where he uses most resources etc?

Comment: You _cannot_ tick every ms. The `Timer` uses `sleep` to wait - `sleep` has a resolution of around 15ms at best. Without busy-waiting and using `System.nanoTime()` you cannot have a higher resolution than around 15ms.

Comment: @BoristheSpider okay, that I've been able to verify thanks. Still, it used to be a lot faster. But then I'm assuming the whole problem lies in the wakeup which is actually slower than the 15ms. I should probably look at some more threading then.

EDIT: also, even with this 15ms, it should take him less than the 10sec he is using now, I hope :/

Comment: I don't now the internals of `Timer`, but I think if the `Task` runs longer than 1ms, than it will delay the subsequent `Task`s.

Comment: I would assume that before you didn't have much going on so the `Thread` was generally awoken on time. Now you may have more going on - the fact is that once the `Thread` is asleep it is the OS-level `Thread` scheduler that wakes it up - so it could even be something external to your application.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Would using 
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor solve this issue then? I've read that allows for more concurrent threads so I could effectively split up the game in more threads than I already do. (I have a seperate thread for the GUI atm).

Comment: You cannot `sleep` with that resolution, regardless of which method you pick. If you want to get 1ms resolution you will have to busy wait. You could try [`LockSupport.parkNanos`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#parkNanos(long)) but I have no idea what improvement that brings.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I am in possession of heavily tested code which sleeps with *accuracy* (precision is the wrong term) below 1 ms. I use a Scheduled Executor Service.

Comment: For completeness I should add that the accuracy is mid-term: in each second I get the appropriate number of tasks scheduled, while at the resolution of 1 ms there is probably some jitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually have a bit of a ad-hoc solution to the problem.
I stopped counting every ms, and just did the +=15ms to counter for the sleep();

The timer runs smooth now and after a minute I had less than 1second difference with the actual time it should have been.

Thanks everyone for your help, but any other (less ad-hoc) solutions are still very welcome!

EDIT: I just got this method due to Boris, so you can post your comment as an answer if you like :)

Answer (score 1):

If long-term accuracy of scheduling is what you are after, then you should use the [`Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) method. If you continually reschedule the task with a delay, then the `Timer` instance cannot compensate for its past timing errors.

If short-term accuracy is also a concern, then you should switch to the Scheduled Executor Service, which uses a more accurate low-level technique to schedule the tasks.